# Android app - PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat not available

Tags: java, android, preference

I am currently trying to create a custom Preference with a Datepicker.

For that purpose I've found a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@JakobUlbrich/building-a-settings-screen-for-android-part-3-ae9793fd31ec).

Next to the xml, the first step was to create a class "TimePreference" which extends "DialogPreference".

The second class was "TimePreferenceFragmentCompat" which extends "PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat".
But in my Android Studio I can't find the "PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat" class.

Nor does `import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat;` work.

Does someone know what I may am missing? Are there any new ways to do what i want to achieve? (I didn't found anything newer than this tutorial).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you import the support library correctly ? com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0

Comment: In the Android SDK Manager under "Extras" the "Android Support Repository" is installed.
In build.gradle(Module: app) I have this: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line to your Gradle dependencies:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'
```

Comment: I've just had to change the version from 24.2.1 to 25.1.1 and it worked. Thanks! :)